# Is there any reason to *not* compress a JAR?

Tags: jar

Netbeans has an option to compress JARs after building them. Is there any reason to *not* do this? Does it make the JVM start slower maybe? Why aren't JARs compressed automatically by all compilers without giving you the option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may possibly make the JVM start an infinitesimally amount of time slower than usual.

Comment: @Coronatust: Your answer is not clear for me. Do you mean jvm starts slower with the compression *on* or *off*? Maybe you can edit it.